# Retag request: replace

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

There are lots of replace [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) on SO that are very similar:

- [search-and-replace](/questions/tagged/search-and-replace) (413)
- [find-and-replace](/questions/tagged/find-and-replace) (312)
- [search-replace](/questions/tagged/search-replace) (13)

Could somebody please combine them?